# Как в unity сравнить два объекта и не спавнить такой же объект в случае совпадения?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть скрипт, который при запуске присваивает кучу параметров объекту. Есть еще один скрипт, который отвечает за спавн этих объектов. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы два объекта с одинаковыми параметрами НЕ спавнились. Наверно, нужно сравнивать каждый объект, который собирается появиться со всеми, которые уже есть на сцене...

```
public class ObjectChooserScript : MonoBehaviour {

public int param1 = 0;
public int param2 = 0;
public int param3 = 0;
public int param4 = 0;
public int param5 = 0;
public int param6 = 0;

void Start () {

param1 = Random.Range (0, 4);
param2 = Random.Range (0, 7);
param3 = Random.Range (0, 5);
param4 = Random.Range (0, 5);
param5 = Random.Range (0, 9);
param6 = Random.Range (0, 2);
}
```

Здесь параметры присваиваются именно во время запуска.

А вот сам скрипт спавнер.

```
public class ObjectSpawnerScript : MonoBehaviour {
public Transform myObject;
public int maxObjects = 10;
public int curObjects = 0;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    for (int i = curObjects; i < maxObjects; i++) {
// тут просто определяются координаты, по которым создается объект
            Instantiate (myObject, new Vector3(Random.Range (-9, 9)
                                           , Random.Range(-3, 6)
                                           , Random.Range(0, 4)), Quaternion.identity);
            curObjects++;

        }
}
```

Как мне сравнить объекты по всем параметрам, кроме `param6` (мне даже вроде объекты сравнивать не надо, а просто параметры?), и, в случае совпадения, не создать объект с такими же параметрами? В общем, мне нужно, чтобы на сцене не было двух одинаковых объектов

Comment: два одинаковых объекта это те, у которых попарно параметры с 1 по 5 совпадают? то есть у одного с 1 по 4 параметр совпадают, а 5-ый нет - это уже не одинаковые, так?

Comment: Все верно. А шестой параметр может как совпадать, так и нет - это не важно

Comment: В принципе добавил ответ, в том числе и сравнение параметров объектов. В теории должно работать)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложу вариантик:

В классе `ObjectChooserScript` убираете из метода `Start` всю рандомную генерацию. Оставить можно разве что генерацию у параметра 6, раз он может остаться и не важен для сравнений. Делаете там метод `InitParams`, куда после инстанциирования прилетят параметры класса:

```
public void InitParams(params int[] myparams) {
    param1 = myparams[0];
    param2 = myparams[1];
    // ...  и т.д.
}
```

При старте объекта будет только так:

```
void Start () {
    param6 = Random.Range(0, 2);
}
```

Хотя даже нет... эту строку можно также поместить в `InitParams` последней строкой. Тогда в `Start` вообще этого всего не будет (или будет что-то еще).

Далее в скрипте спауна `ObjectSpawnerScript` размещаете список, содержащий массивы:

```
List<int[]> arrayList = new List<int[]>();
```

и делаете функцию, которая, как раз-таки, генерирует рандомные числа в массив. В ней проверяется, есть ли такой массив в списке и если да —  перевызывается функция, если нет, то происходит:

- Добавление массива в список
- Инстанциирование объекта
- Присваивание данному объекту параметров через `InitParams(Здесь массив с рандомными числами)`

Получится примерно так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

List<int[]> arrayList = new List<int[]>();

int[] GenerateRandom() {
    int[] params = new int[5];
    params[0] = Random.Range (0, 4);
    params[1] = Random.Range (0, 7);
    params[2] = Random.Range (0, 5);
    params[3] = Random.Range (0, 5);
    params[4] = Random.Range (0, 9);

    // тут логика сравнения массива с массивами в списке
    // Если есть совпадение, то перевызываем метод GenerateRandom()
    foreach (var array in arrayList) {                
        if (myparams.Length == array.Length && myparams.Intersect(array).Count() == myparams.Length) {                                      
            return GenerateParams();
        }                
    }

    // если всё норм, то добавляем в список:
    // возвращаем массив:       
    arrayList.Add(myparams);
    return myparams;
}


for (int i = curObjects; i < maxObjects; i++) {
    // Берем индивидуальный список уникальных параметров
    var myparams = GenerateRandom();
    // Инстанциируем объект
    var myobj = Instantiate (myObject, new Vector3(Random.Range (-9, 9)
                                   , Random.Range(-3, 6)
                                   , Random.Range(0, 4)), Quaternion.identity);
    // пихаем в него параметры
    myobj.InitParams(myparams);
    curObjects++;
}
```

Всё это можно доработать, если угодно. Мысль, думаю, понятна: генерировать массив с параметрами в классе спауна, если такого еще нет, то инициализировать объект с передачей в него эти самые параметры.

---

P.S. Так как операция может быть накладной для такой генерации, то можно это делать не в главном потоке, а с помощью корутины (coroutine), тогда зависания главного потока (если вдруг таковые будут) можно будет избежать.

Comment: спасибо, более-менее разобрался

Comment: @KremSoda хорошо. если будут вопросы попробую более-менее пояснить что-то))

Answer (score 1):

Есть вероятность зависаний при рандомной генерации и поиске  элементов с теми же параметрами. Можно  хранить состояние параметров (получится что-то вроде перебора всех сочетаний). А если объекты удаляются, то заносить их в список. И когда нужен будет объект берем первый из списка, если тот пуст, то находим новое сочетание.

Не тестировал:

```
   public class Param
{
    public int Value;
    public int TLim; 
    public int DLim; 

    public Param(int d, int t)
    {
        TLim = t;
        DLim = d;
        Value = d;
    }
}

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    Param[] param = new Param[5];
    GameObject PrefabWithObjectChooserScript;
    static List<int[]> Combinations = new List<int[]>();

    void Start()
    {        
        param[0] = new Param(0, 2);
        param[1] = new Param(0, 3);
        param[2] = new Param(0, 4);
        param[3] = new Param(0, 4);
        param[4] = new Param(0, 3);


    }
// Вызвать эту функцию для генерации нового объекта. 
    public void Generate()
    {
        if(Combinations.Count > 0)
        {
            var go = Instantiate(PrefabWithObjectChooserScript) as GameObject;
            go.GetComponent<ObjectChooserScript>().Init(Combinations[Combinations.Count - 1]);
            Combinations.RemoveAt(Combinations.Count - 1);

            return;
        }



        for (int i = param.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            if (param[i].Value != param[i].TLim)
            {
                int[] values = new int[param.Length];
                for (int g = 0; g < param.Length; ++g)
                    values[g] += param[g].Value;

                var go = Instantiate(PrefabWithObjectChooserScript) as GameObject;
                go.GetComponent<ObjectChooserScript>().Init(values);

                ++param[i].Value;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < param.Length; ++j)
                {
                    param[j].Value = param[j].DLim;
                }

                return;
            }
        }

        Debug.Log("Больше нет доступных комбинаций");
    }


    public static void ReturnValues(int [] values)
    {
        Combinations.Add(values);
    }
}



public class ObjectChooserScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int [] param = new int[5];

    public void Init(int[] p)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; ++i)
            param[i] = p[i];        
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        Spawner.ReturnValues(param);
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, к сожалению, нельзя принять сразу два ответа, поэтому галочку поставил тому, кто был первее